# I am a novice programmer of c back ground and learning java. Can anyone tell me that why this code below gives an error

Tags: java

```
package javaapplication4;
import java.util.*;

public class Practice {
    public static void main (String[] args){

       int[] a = {12,1,12,3,12,1,1,2,3,3};

       int len = a.length;
       int[] b = new int[len];

       int c;
       int d;
       for (c=0;c<len;c++){

           d=a[c];
           System.out.println(d);

           System.out.println(b[d]);


       }

    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5554734/3788176).

Answer (score 2):

Error: `b[d]` when `d` is equal to `a[0]`, i.e `12`

`b[12]` throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 0):

```
   int[] a = {12,1,12,3,12,1,1,2,3,3};
               ^--- "d" on you first loop iteration

       System.out.println(b[12]);
                             ^---"d" on the first loop iteration
```

You don't have 12 elements in your array, you're accessing beyond the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Array index starts from 0. So the last element always has an index of length-of-the-array - 1.

Why is this question tagged `C`?

Answer (score 0):

This array

```
int[] a = {12,1,12,3,12,1,1,2,3,3};
```

has only 10 elements.

The array `b` defined the following way

```
int len = a.length;
int[] b = new int[len];
```

also has only 10 elements.

In this statement

```
System.out.println(b[d]);
```

you are using the values of elements of the array `a` as indices for the array `b`. And it is evident that for example value `12` is greater than the number of elements in `b`.